# Do variables declared in loop make space complexity O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, loops, memory, big-o, space-complexity

Would variables declared inside of a `for` loop that loops N times make the space complexity O(N) even though those variables fall out of scope each time the loop repeats?

```
for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){
  var num = i + 5;
}
```

Comment: No, that's considered constant space. So O(1) in total.

Comment: Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Would variables declared inside an O(N) for loop make the space complexity O(N)

**No**, since variables go out of scope at the end of every iteration, thus they are destroyed.

As a result the space complexity remains constant, i.e. O(1).

Answer (score 3):

1 (fixed-size) variable that you change `n` times (which could include unallocating and reallocating it) is still just 1 variable, thus `O(1)` space.

But this may possibly be somewhat language-dependent - if some language (or compiler) decides to keep all of those earlier declarations of the variable in memory, that's going to be `O(n)`, not `O(1)`.

Consider, for example, two ways of doing this in C++:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   int num = i + 5;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   int* num = new int(i + 5);
```

In the former case, the variable can be reused and it will be `O(1)`.

When you use `new`, that memory will not be automatically freed, so every iteration in the latter case will assign more memory instead of reusing the old (technically the pointer will get reused, but what it pointed to will remain), thus it will use `O(n)` space. Doing this is a terrible idea and will be a memory leak, but it's certainly possible.

(I'm not too sure what the C++ standard says about what compilers are or are not required to do in each case, this is mostly just meant to show that this type of in-loop assignment is not necessarily always O(1)).

Answer (score 1):

No, it remains `O(1)` as explained below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){
  var num = i + 5; //allocate space for var `num`
} // release space acquired by `num`
```